# How to draw horizontal arrows from y axis to graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw a similar image to the one below. Is it possible to do this in TikZ?

[image]

Comment: Have you started a minimal working example? if yes please provide it to help the people willing to help you, so they don't start from scratch. there is more chance someone helps you if you give a start.

Comment: See also my answer to [Draw arrows from axis to curve](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286221/4778).

Comment: @Alenanno, in my stock of interesting answers on SX I have answer, foe which I forgot to make note where is original ... Now I will complete it with this data. My answer is based on it ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->]   (-0.1, 0) -- (3,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]   (0, -0.1) -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$};
%
\draw[name path=A,
      red, very thick]  (0,0) .. controls +(2,1) and +(0,-1) .. (2,4);
      \foreach \i [count=\ix] in {0.5,1,...,3.5}
{
\path[name path=B\ix]   (0,\i) -- + (3,0);
\draw[name intersections={of=A and B\ix, by={a}}];
\draw[thick,-{Triangle[]}]         (0,\i) -- (a);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Draw of dashed line I left you ...

Answer (score 2):

In plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) there are two macros, called `cutbefore` and `cutafter`, that help with this type of drawing.

[image: A red curve with arrows touching it]

This is produced from:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

numeric u;
u = 1cm;

path xx, yy, ff;
xx = (left--3 right) scaled u;
yy = (origin--4 up)  scaled u;
ff = origin .. {up} (2.5u,4u);

draw ff withcolor .67 red;

for t=1 upto 8:
  drawarrow xx shifted (0,1/2t*u)
            cutbefore yy
            cutafter ff;
endfor

draw xx;
draw yy;

endfig;
end.
```

To draw the arrows, I've reused the `xx` path created for the x-axis.  At each step in the loop, it's shifted up, and cut off at the y-axis and the curve before being drawn.

### Additional notes

Plain Metapost defines `left` to be `(-1,0)`, `right` to be `(1,0)`, `up` as `(0,1)` and `down` as `(0,-1)`.  I find that I get less confused when I write `4 up` instead of `(0,4)`.

I've drawn the `ff` curve first, so that the arrow tips are on top of it.  This looks better than if they are underneath it.  But for a more professional job it would be better to shorten the arrows slightly.  You can do this my moving the line that cuts them off a little bit to the left.  So if you replace

```
cutafter ff;
```

with

```
cutafter ff shifted 2/3 left;
```

you get this slightly neater result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.2,-0.2)(2.2,4.5)
  \psaxes[
    labels = none,
    ticks = none
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-0.2)(2.2,4.5)
  \psplot[
    linecolor = red
  ]{0}{2.1}{x dup mul}
  \multido{\r = 0.4+0.4}{10}{\psline{->}(0,\r)(!\r\space sqrt \r\space)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that `\r\space sqrt` (`sqrt(\r)` in PostScript notation) is the inverse function of `x dup mul` (`x^2` in PostScript notation).